# How can I make a patch request in vuejs and also update marks input for individuals using v-model

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

Hello please I am working on a student assessment input form using vuejs, express and mongoDB. I am done with the backend API and its working fine using postman for testing. Below is the code.

```
// UPDATE MARKS
router.patch('/:studentId', async (req, res) => {
    try{
    const updatedStudent = await Assessment.updateMany({_id: req.params.studentId},
        {
            $push:
            { homework: req.body.homework,
              classtest:req.body.classtest, 
              projectwork:req.body.projectwork, 
              exams:req.body.exams },
        });
        res.json(updatedStudent);
            }catch (err) {
                res.json({ message: err });
    }
});
```

I am stuck with getting it work with the vuejs frontend. I created a JavaScript file 'assessment.js' to make all the request in there as below;

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:9000/contAssessment/';
   ...
    // Add Marks
    static addMarks(homework) {
        return axios.patch(url, {
            homework
        });
    }
}

export default assessmentService;
```

I have imported it into the marks component form as below;

```
<template>
    <div id="container">
        <div 
            v-for="assessment in assessments" 
            v-bind:key="assessment._id"
            >
            <div id="students_marks_info"
            v-if="assessment.students.classes===classes"
            > 
            <p> {{assessment.students.name}} </p> 
            <p> <input type="text" v-model="homework"> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" v-on:click="addMarks(homework)">Submit</button>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import assessmentService from '../assessmentService';

export default {
  name: 'marksEntryForm',
  data() {
    return {
      assessments: [],
      error: '',
      classes: '',
      homework: []
    }
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      this.assessments = await assessmentService.getAssessments();
    } catch(err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }
  },
  methods: {
   async addMarks() {
      await assessmentService.addMarks(this.homework);
      this.assessments = await assessmentService.getAssessments();
      }
    }}
</script>
```

I am getting a 404 bad request anytime I click the buttom to run the method addMarks. I also have problem with the input. Anytime I enter marks for a student, the same marks appears at other students inputs. Please I need your kind response on this issue since I am new to vuejs and using axios to make patch request. Thank you

Comment: The URLs look different. You are missing :studentId in vuejs. 404 means the URL does not exist. If it was a problem with the URL it would have been 405 - Method Not Supported

Answer (score 0):

Your router on the server is `here_is_your_url/:studentId`, but in requrest from front to `http://localhost:9000/contAssessment/`(doesn't have a `:studentId`)

Comment: I added `:studentId` to the URL as you directed me. The error code `404` is gone, thank you, but the inputs are still not pushing into arrays(i.e homework, exams.   etc). I copied a particular student's id and placed it at `:studentsId` directly and the input value was pushed to the individual records and it worked when I clicked the button.

Comment: But your router on backend `/:studentId` from root or from `/contAssessment`? Where you include this route?

Comment: ...I am thinking that the problem might have to do with setting the studentsId as parameter in the **marks component** or the link between `**marks component and assessment.js**. Can you please help me with getting the studentsId at the url, on clicking.

Comment: my router from the backend is from the URL `const url = 'http://localhost:9000/contAssessment/'`, Now this is what I have in the request file,``` // Add Marks
    static addMarks(homework, id) {
        return axios.patch(`${url}${id}`, {
            homework
        });
    }```

Comment: so your request url should be `http://localhost:9000/:studentId` (protocol://domain:port/path).  Where `:studentId` is Number

Comment: Yes, `/:studentId` is a unique Id from my mongoDB database. The problem I am facing now is how I can get this number to be placed at the end of the URL when i click the button in the ** addMark** component.

Comment: In the **addMark** component, I currently have this method ,`methods: {
   async addMarks(id) {
      await assessmentService.addMark(this.homework,id);
      this.assessments = await assessmentService.getAssessments();
      }
    }}`

Comment: And in the template of the **addMark** component, i also have this, `<div 
            v-for="assessment in assessments"
            v-bind:item="assessment" 
            v-bind:key="assessment._id"
            >
            <div id="students_marks_info"
            v-if="assessment.students.classes===classes"
            > 
            <p> {{assessment.students.name}} </p> 
            <p> <input type="text" v-model="homework" :key="assessment._id"> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" v-on:click="addMarks(assessment._id)">Submit</button>`